# Android add custom property to View.animate().*

Tags: android, view, sdk

Is it possible to add a custom property to View.animate().* in Android 4.x?

Android 4.x provides View.animate() which then allows several properties to be animated.
Like:

```
View.animate().alpha(0.5f).setDuration.start();
```

I want to add a custom property to this object like:

```
CustomView.animate().xyz(0.1f).setDuration.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a custom animation:

```
public class CustomAnim extends Animation {

    private CustomView mLayout;
    private float finalVal;
    private float startVal;

    public CustomAnim(CustomView layout, float finalVal) {
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.finalVal = finalVal;
        this.startVal = layout.xyz();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        mLayout.setXYZ(interpolatedTime * (finalVal - startVal) + startVal);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Alternatively, if your property has a getter and setter method such as setXYZ getXYZ you can use [property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Comment: This is just not what I was looking for. A (s)troll through the Android code revealed that it isn't possible to do what my original question asked in Android 4.x SDK. I'm leaving this here in case any future version of Android SDK allows it.